# Why does 'delete' operation(Not max or min) of heap take O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap

It is known that deleting operation on a heap take `O(n)`(NOTICE: not max or min value). I know that heap is not suitable for deleting or updating, but kinda curious.

I think that if I want to delete certain element, I think just `percDown(element)` and `heapSize--` make it done....So I think it takes `O(logn)`?

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the standard array-based complete binary tree implementation.

The short answer is that it doesn't need to. If you maintain a parallel map from objects in the heap to the indices where they're stored, then you can delete in O(log n) using sifting operations to restore the heap property to "fill the hole" created by the deletion.

Naive implementations require O(n) because they begin by searching the heap array. There's nothing about the heap property that helps make this more efficient than O(n).

If you're interested, [here is an implementation](https://github.com/gene-ressler/lulu/blob/master/ext/lulu/pq.c) that keeps a heap of indices into an object array (rather than keeping the objects in the heap nodes) and a reverse index - just an array of integers - that takes an index in the object array to its index in the heap array.  This reverse map doesn't change the asymptotic run time of any of the other operations, but it provides O(log n) delete.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps :)